# How do I solve Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

**When I try to launch MySQL from the XAMP launcher I get this error**

`12:41:34 PM  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.`

`12:41:34 PM  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,`

`12:41:34 PM  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.`

`12:41:34 PM  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check`

`12:41:34 PM  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues`

`12:41:34 PM  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this`

`12:41:34 PM  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums`

**When I check the logs this is what I get:**

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 23696`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 714125; transaction id 963`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.`

`2024-02-08 11:48:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(`

How do I fix this problem?

I've tried restarting my system and that didn't work, I thought maybe a port was being used by another program I had started. so I stopped

```
MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB
```

Tried these solutions

- Trying to Stop MySQL Service
- Use MySQL Backup Folder
- Trying to Repair MySQL Database with Shell
- Change Client and Server Ports
- deleting the ibdata1 file

I don't want to have to reinstall XAMP as I do not want to lose my database

Answer (score 0):

I decided to bite the bullet and reinstalled XAMP that solved my problem. I guess I'll need to start making regular backups of my databases incase this happens again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).